# Add Quantity to a Recipe habtm Ingredients Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, design-patterns, has-and-belongs-to-many, recipe

I wanted to build a basic cookbook. With a Recipes habtm Ingredients Relation.

My first attempt was like this.

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  # title, description
  has_many :recipe_ingredients
end

class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  # name, unit
  has_many :recipe_ingredients
  has_many :recipes, :through => :recipe_ingredients
end

class RecipeIngredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :recipe
  belongs_to :ingredient
  attr_accessible :amount
end
```

And created the Relation by Hand

```
RecipeIngredient.create(:recipe_id => 1, :ingredient_id => 2, :amount => 100)

recipe.recipe_ingredients.amout
recipe.recipe_ingredients.ingredient.unit
recipe.recipe_ingredients.ingredient.name
```

This feels ugly. But I don't know any other solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks fine to me, as a schema/approach.  I think it might just feel ugly because your choice of class name leads you to type "recipe.recipe_ingredients.ingredient" a lot.  To me, an 'ingredient' is the food/liquid/whatever AS IT IS USED IN THE RECIPE, so the join table should be called 'ingredients'.  Each ingredient has a quantity and links to a 'product' or an 'item' or something similar.

I would rename it thus:

```
Recipe
  has_many :ingredients
  has_many :items, :through => :ingredients

Ingredient
  #fields - recipe_id, item_id, quantity(string)
  belongs_to :recipe
  belongs_to :item

Item
  has_many :ingredients
  has_many :recipes, :through => :ingredients
```

Now on your view page you can say

```
<h2><%= recipe.name %></h2>
<dl>
  <% @recipe.ingredients.each do |ingredient| %>
    <dt><%= ingredient.item.name %></dt>
    <dd><%= ingredient.quantity %></dd>
  <% end %>
</dl>
```

Comment: Yay typing recipes.recipes... is bad. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess you were missing has_many:through in receipe model

class Receipe < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many    :receipe_ingredients

has_many    :ingredients, :through => :receipe_ingredients

end

class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many    :receipe_ingredients

has_many    :receipes, :through => :receipe_ingredients

end

class ReceipeIngredient < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :receipe

belongs_to :ingredient

end